# Entity Framework 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column' error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I understand what the error message is saying. I'm just not sure why it is saying it. My table has an Identity and it is set to auto-increment, yet when I go to save an entity I get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Conferences' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I'm using a code-first approach and my `Conference` entity looks like this:

```
public class Conference
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DugoutId { get; set; }
    public int ConferenceDetailsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Dugout Dugout { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ConferenceDetail ConferenceDetail { get; set; }
}
```

When I am going to save the Conference, the values are as follows:

```
Id: 0
DugoutId: 15
ConferenceDetailsId: 1
Dugout: null
ConferenceDetail: null
```

Any ideas why this won't save?

Comment: You should add your dbcontext, that will give us more idea as to whats wrong. Is Conference a table or view? Also, check the query that EF is creating while inserting using a profiler or in debug. It looks like ConferenceDetail is a view and EF tries to insert data into conferencedetail table for the same ID, however, that record already exists in conference table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ForeignKey] attibutes are pointing to wrong property for Dugout and ConferenceDetails. Should be ForeignKey("DugoutId") and ForeignKey("ConferenceDetailsId").

Comment: This was my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @halterdev - Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using code first or is the code being generated automatically?
Depending on what you are doing, there might be a mismatch between the model and the database. You can try and use a profiler to know exactly what EF is trying to do.
This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682504/ef-code-first-giving-me-error-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-i) could help you as well.

Comment: Is it a new table? If so, you might try deleting it and running your code again just to make sure the model was created correctly.