# EF Core Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947733/entity-framework-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682504/ef-code-first-giving-me-error-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-i) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004098/ef-core-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-sqlexception), however the following error is not gone:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Products' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What I've tried is:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Moreover, I've tried to set to `None`:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

`T-SQL` code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DatePlaced datetime NOT NULL,   
    CONSTRAINT PK_Order_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE OrderItems
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    IdOrder INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_OrderItems_IdOrder__Orders_Id FOREIGN KEY(IdOrder) REFERENCES Orders(Id),
    IdProduct INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_OrderItems_IdProduct__Products_Id FOREIGN KEY(IdProduct) REFERENCES Products(Id),
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    TotalPrice decimal (18,2),  
    CONSTRAINT PK_OrderItem_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Products
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name varchar(100), 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Product_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

And model classes look like this:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DatePlaced { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    public Product() { }

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }       

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and `Customer` model:

```
public class Customer : IdentityUser
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to save `Order` and `OrderItems`. The code of saving looks like this:

```
public async Task Add(Order order)
{
    order.Customer = _context.Customers.Find(order.Customer.Id);    
    await _context.AddAsync(order);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

and `OrderService` class:

```
    public async Task<OrderDto> Add(OrderDto orderDto)
    {
        var order = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderDto);
        await _orderRepository.Add(order);        
        orderDto.Id = order.Id;
        return orderDto;

    }
```

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong? Please, do not close my question as it is not duplicate.

Comment: Looks like it's an error in itself that Products get inserted at all.

Comment: Not being an expert with EF, I will comment instead of answer, but I believe `AddAsync` adds the entity to the context in the Added state so it's trying to insert it. It already has an id because you just did a `Find` of it (presumably). I think you can just remove the second line of code in the `Add()` method.

Comment: @GertArnold do you mean that **Product** inserts again?

Comment: Yes, as @Crowcoder explained better than I did.

Comment: @CrowCoder do you mean this row to delete ‘ await _context.AddAsync(order);’?  But how will Entity Framework know that I want to insert ‘Order’?

Comment: @GertArnold could you show please how a code should look like?

Comment: Based on the error, I assumed the `Order` you passed in is already tracked by the context. You haven't shown what happens before the call to `Add()` so I don't know. If that is not the case then I don't know.

Comment: I'd add `OrderId` and `ProductId` to `OrderItem`. No need to set the full objects.

Comment: @GertArnold could you see my answer? Maybe you will have some thoughts? I think it is bad solution. If you would like to see my whole code, then I’ve uploaded to Github   https://github.com/NiceStepUp/eshop

Comment: @Crowcoder could you see my answer? Maybe you will have some thoughts? I think it is bad solution. If you would like to see my whole code, then I’ve uploaded to Github   https://github.com/NiceStepUp/eshop

Comment: As I already mentioned I'm not an EF expert, but I can guarantee you are not required to make random queries in order to perform an insert. Now, you said that EF generated an insert into [AspNetUsers] when you tried to insert an Order. That makes no sense. I think you have a few wires crossed and I'm sorry but there is not enough context to see it.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for your help. Maybe it could  be useful for you the reason why it was, so I decided to make own answer to my question

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your help. Maybe it is useful for you to know the reason why it was, so I decided to make own answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this behaviour is that `Automapper` creates a new instance and Entity Framework thinks that POCO's are all new entities which should be inserted.

So the solution is to `Attach` existing entities to `DbContext. [It is described in great tutorial here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships/managing-one-to-many-relationships).

So the solution looks like this:

```
public async Task Add(Order order)
{            
    _context.Attach(order.Customer);
    foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
    {
        _context.Attach(orderItem.Product);
    }            
    await _context.Orders.AddAsync(order);
}
```

The whole code looks like this.

Service Layer:

```
public async Task<OrderDto> Add(OrderDto orderDto)
{
    var order = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderDto);
    await _orderRepository.Add(order);        
    orderDto.Id = order.Id;
    return orderDto;
}
```

Repository Layer:

```
public async Task Add(Order order)
{            
    _context.Attach(order.Customer);
    foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
    {
        _context.Attach(orderItem.Product);
    }            
    await _context.Orders.AddAsync(order);
}
```

Comment: I should have stuck with EF6. Many to many relationship tables were easier to handle when I was on EF 6. Had this same issue like this

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use `_mapper.Map(sourceProperty, destinationProperty);`. This does not change the reference. However, when you setup the configuration, make sure to ignore the property you don't want to map (i.e. primary key).

e.g. under constructor of the mapping profile class:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
.ForMember(destination => destination.PK, options => options.Ignore());
```