# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'APIMapping' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am running into a problem with an IDENTITY_INSERT problem as described in title. The Price class has a child object that is linked by a foreign key in the db called ApimappingId.
The db classes below are auto generated using Scaffold-DbContext command.

Edit* i think the cause is it is trying to insert the child Apimapping object that i loaded into the price object.

Main Program

```
using (FinanceDBContext financeDBContext = new FinanceDBContext())
{
    foreach (var item in priceList)
    {
        financeDBContext.Price.Add(item);
    }

    financeDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Price

```
public partial class Price
{
    public int PriceId { get; set; }
    public decimal LastPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    public decimal Ask { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int? ApimappingId { get; set; }

    public Apimapping Apimapping { get; set; }
}
```

ApiMapping

```
public partial class Apimapping
{
    public Apimapping()
    {
        Price = new HashSet<Price>();
    }

    public int ApimappingId { get; set; }
    public int? ExchangeId { get; set; }
    public int? SecurityId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public Exchange Exchange { get; set; }
    public Security Security { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Price> Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't use EF much but nobody else is rushing to answer so I think you need to decorate your id's with the identity [DatabaseGeneratedOption](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute). I would have thought the scaffolding would be smart enough to do that.

Comment: See if this question helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682504/ef-code-first-giving-me-error-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-i/4683001  Specifically try the [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] mentioned

Comment: @Crowcoder that did not work. I got the following error... The property 'ApimappingId' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate' because the key value cannot be changed after the entity has been added to the store.

I didnt think it would be necessary to touch the auto generated classes from the model

Comment: @user7396598 did not work. Besides running the scafolding command to sync further db changes will override the setting in the auto generated file

Comment: i believe the cause is it is trying to insert the child object Apimapping when it doesnt need to be when price is added

Comment: What is `priceList`? How does it get populated? How does your code snippet obtain it? That seems to be the key and you didn't include any details about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ApiMapping ID, it's more than enough and try to turn of the eager loading.

If you don't want to set to null turn of tracking off of those objects.

```
//if you want to load all 
context.ApiMappings.AsNoTracking().ToList(); 

// Use condition if you have some condition
context.ApiMappings.Where(x => apimappingIds.Contains(x.ApimappingId)).AsNoTracking().ToList();

//You can detach each entity also
dbContext.Entry(item.Apimapping).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set to null the child object. I am not sure why entity framework thought the child already needed adding when it existed already.

If someone could give a better solution to add objects without having to nullify children, i will accept their answer thanks

```
    using (FinanceDBContext financeDBContext = new FinanceDBContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in priceList)
        {
            item.Apimapping = null;
            financeDBContext.Price.Add(item);
        }

        financeDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```