# SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Recipe' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

**Errors:**

SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Recipe' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

**Program.cs**

1. I had add two category "Breakfast" and "Lunch".
2. Could make a new Recipe there belongs to "BreakFast"
3. If I try add a new recipe i get the error.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (RecipesEntities context = new RecipesEntities())
        {
            //context.Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Breakfast" });
            //context.Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Lunch" });

            //new receipe and assign it to these two new categories

            // 1. Using Id properties 
            //Category category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Breakfast");
            //context.Recipes.Add(new Recipe { Name = "Cereal", CategoryId = category.Id });


            // 2. Recipe.Category navigation property
            Category category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Lunch");
            context.Recipes.Add(new Recipe { Name = "Pizza", Category = category });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**My database design**

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Wzy.png)

[Category Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7xfr.png)

[Category Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG1Wy.png)

[Recipe Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOeqa.png)  Here should be a pizza.

[Recipe Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqlMi.png)

Comment: Can you share your Recipe-class?

Comment: public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

Comment: You could try to add the [Key]-annotation to your Id and also check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48976370/3085985) helps.

Comment: I get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but for anyone who sees this [here is a link to the Microsoft Docs explaining how to fix it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties#explicit-values-into-sql-server-identity-columns)

For your problem, you can try to fix it by surrounding your save with opening and closing of the Identity Insert.

```
context.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Recipe ON");
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Recipe OFF");
}
finally
{
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```