# Erro: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table - INT to tinyInt

Tags: c#, database

I'm working on a ASP .NET WEB EF project. I get this error while trying to update the database with 'Update-Migration'.

It says: Error Number:544,State:1,Class:16
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genres' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Others had this issue before.
I tried to apply methods suggested by others on this issue on this website. Among the solutions, one could probably be a fix for my problem is that I have type tinyInt for the PK of the table. That make sense, because i have changed it via [Required] data anotation.

Question: How can I change it back to type INT or simply solve this issue?

Link to the suggestions I followed is : 
[EF Code First giving me error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'People' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682504/ef-code-first-giving-me-error-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-i)

At the bottom of the thread is mentioned about setting : this.Property(t => t.TableID).HasColumnName("TableID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

But it is not mentionen where? I use VS 2017.

This is the genre class:

```
 public class Genre
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the blank Migration that I have created and then populated with sql code:

```
    // <auto-generated />

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyNotes.Migrations
{
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure;
    using System.Resources;

    [GeneratedCode("EntityFramework.Migrations", "6.2.0-61023")]
    public sealed partial class PopulateGenresTable : IMigrationMetadata
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

        private readonly ResourceManager Resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(PopulateGenresTable));

    string IMigrationMetadata.Id
    {
        get { return "201809211642586_PopulateGenresTable"; }
    }

    string IMigrationMetadata.Source
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    string IMigrationMetadata.Target
    {
        get { return Resources.GetString("Target"); }
    }
    }
}
```

The error appear when I try to run Update-Database after creating changes to this file:

```
namespace MyNotes.Migrations
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class PopulateGenresTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (ID, Name) VALUES (1,'Medicine')");
            Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (ID, Name) VALUES (2,'Philosophy')");

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            Sql("DELETE FROM Genres WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because you declared the ID as an autogenerated column, SQL Server won't allow you to specifically insert values for this column. So you should add records as follows:

```
Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Name) VALUES ('Medicine')");
Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Name) VALUES ('Philosophy')");
```

Comment: Great! It helps at least update-database without error, but now I don't set the database being populated with these values.

Comment: second issue will be what about the down() method. How to reference there if I don't mention the ID?

Comment: For your concern with `Down()` method: you can simply `DELETE FROM Genres` which deletes all the records in the table. Regarding the missing records are you looking in the right DB?

Comment: Also, when you execute `Update-Database` command, do you see your migration PopulateGenresTable being applied?

Comment: I suggest you close VS, delete packages, obj, and bin folders, then re-open the solution, let it restore packages and build again

Comment: Now I did restart VS. I can see it has populated with only two value. I added few more values to populate the Genres, but it doesn't more than those two.

Comment: Most likely because the migration is already applied to the DB. Subsequent Update-Database commands, only apply new migrations. You can see that in the Package Manager output; it should be something like 'Applying explicit migration <migration name>'. If you need to add more data, you need to create a new migration, or delete the DB, and all migrations are re-applied

Comment: Thank you very much Claudiu :) One last issue is about the down(). I have this syntax, but the compiler in migration shows error: Sql("DELETE FROM Genres()");

Comment: remove the () after Genres; it should be DELETE FROM Genres

Comment: Oops. I believe you need to specify the schema for the DELETE statement. So try DELETE FROM dbo.Genres

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180547/discussion-between-newsharper-and-claudiu-tomescu).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model property so it handles auto incrementing for you.

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Comment: I have added [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
to the class Genre, but I still get the same error.

Comment: It needs to go onto your property of the class that is being auto-incremented.

Comment: It says: Error Number:544,State:1,Class:16
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genres' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: You mean it should go inside  public class Genre {  } Right?, but it didn't help with the issue. Still exactly the same!

Comment: I shared the code. In the up() method, there is more lines of sql() code, but i just take few to make it short here.

Comment: I updated my answer, try using the data annotation [ScaffoldColumn(false)].  The interesting thing is that EF should automatically handle the ID column as an autoincrement, but in your case it's saying EF did not setup that column to  be that way so if that new data annotation does not work, I would consider dropping the DB and regenerating it.

Comment: Thanks. Should it go onto the Genre.cs class or the Migration class?

Comment: It is still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180542/discussion-between-newsharper-and-chris-hawkes).